# How do I implement Duck Typing when typing function?

Tags: python

I've got a function:

```
def optimize_image(image) -> BytesIO:
    """
    Takes image and returns it's compressed version if necessary
    """
    pass
```

How do I duck type input and output as objects which implement certain methods (for example, *open()*) instead of specifying certain object types like BytesIO?

Comment: I'm guessing you either want to type hint a `Union` or some specific protocol (https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocols.html)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.IO

Comment: You could make an abstract class and use that. Though keep in mind, that in Python type hints are NOT checked during runtime and are merely for development purposes.

Comment: Looks like implementing abstract class is the best idea, since it can be written for anything (not only Typing.IO) and doesn't need mypy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found creating an abstract class for that purpose to be the best solution. Something like this:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Openable():
    __metaclass__=ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def open():
    """Open object"""

def optimize_image(image: Openable) -> Openable:
    """
    Takes image and returns it's compressed version if necessary
    """
    pass
```